# Selecting week / ISO week number from a date/time field

Tags: sql, date, t-sql, reportbuilder

Sorry - this may be a basic question, but I have been banging my head against this for a week.

I have a database field with the format "*dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss*" called UpdateTime and referencing *max(AuditHistory.ActionedDateTime)* in the database.

I am trying to identify the Week / ISO Week from the date part of this field only using the dataset in ReportBuilder3.

I am trying to achieve an integer entry in a column called "WeekNo" giving me the week of the year that a transaction was made so I can use this for grouping results by year | by week number on a report for senior management.

I have tried many combinations of:
`,DATEPART(WEEK,DAY(max(AuditHistory.ActionedDateTime)) AS WeekNo` and
`,DATEPART(WEEK,MONTH(max(AuditHistory.ActionedDateTime)) AS WeekNo`.

If I use a static date, e.g. `, DATEPART(WEEK,DAY('1900-01-20')) AS WeekNo`, it returns perfectly as "*4*" but I cannot for the life of me get the datepart format correct to identify the week from the format of the field.

I believe my issue is getting SQL to accept that the field is "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss" and work out the week from the date element.

Before I go mad - I thought I'd ask if there is a quick way to achieve this.

Comment: I'd expect ISO week 3 for the date 1900-01-20.

Comment: Aside: If you have a _string_ column containing a date/time formatted as "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss" then you'll likely be disappointed with the value returned by `max`. If the column is a `datetime` (or similar) datatype then there won't be a problem. This is another reason why providing DDL in a question helps us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DATEPART` function expects a `date` / `datetime` / `datetime2` value. You are passing in an integer representing the day or month number.

Assuming you're storing your dates correctly, you just need to pass in the date value directly:

```
DATEPART(WEEK, Max(AuditHistory.ActionedDateTime)) As WeekNo
```

Comment: Thanks Richard - that solved the problem. I had tried multiple resolutions over the last 2 days and you sorted it in such a quick way. I think I may have been under caffeinated for the last few days - obviously a basic error.